# Command gives no output

Tags: discord.py

So I'm making a user info command and when i run the command, it doesn't work and gives no error.

Heres my code:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def info(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
        embed=discord.Embed(color=0xFFFFF0, title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s Info", description="Displays user information.")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}")
        embed.add_field(name="User ID:", value=f"{ctx.author.id}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Color:", value=f"{ctx.author.top_role.mention}\n[{ctx.author.top_role.colour}]")
        embed.add_field(name="Join Date:", value=f"{ctx.author.joined_at}")
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by: {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Are you sure the function is being called correctly? I don't see anything wrong with your code

Comment: Have you set up a class? Have you imported `from discord.ext import commands`? Some more information/code about your structure would be good.

Comment: Yes i have set up a class.

Comment: Have you added the Cog? With `bot.add_cog(CogName(bot))`

Comment: Yes. `def setup(bot): bot.add_cog(Main(bot))
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically put `ctx.author`, which the author is you, you cant show other user's info if you did that. You should use an `if` statement if you want to show other user's info.

And the last thing is the Joindate. it will send this weird time `04:22:23.699000`. So you should convert the time to an `strftime`.

The Updated Code :

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def info(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None): #changed the member to None so it will work if the user didnt mention the member
        if member == None:  # shows that if the use didnt mention the member (if statement)
            member = ctx.author
        # changed all embed of the ctx.author to member
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{member.name}'s Info", description="Displays user information.", color=0xFFFFF0)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=f"{member.avatar_url}")
        embed.add_field(name="User ID:", value=f"{member.id}", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Color:", value=f"{member.top_role.mention}\n[{member.top_role.colour}]")
        embed.add_field(name="Join Date:", value= member.joined_at.strftime("%B %d %Y\n%H:%M:%S %p")) # make the time look nice
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()                                
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by: {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url) # changed member to ctx.author als
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```